# What is the best practice to load JS modules in Blazor client side?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

In Blazor there are several options for executing JavaScript code:

1. Load a js file into the instance of **IJSObjectReference** and call **InvokeAsync** on it:

Blazor component's code behind file:

```cs
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                IJSObjectReference module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", ".script1.js");
                await module.InvokeVoidAsync("sampleFunction1");
            }
        }
```

2. Add a js file as a script to HTML markup and call **InvokeAsync** on **IJSRuntime** instance:

index.html:

```html
<script src="script1.js"></script>
```

Blazor component's code behind file:

```cs
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("sampleFunction1");
            }
        }
```

Both approaches work, but which one is preferred from the perspective of performance, code maintenance and code cleanliness?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the first one (import during OnAfterRenderAsync) and here is my explanation:

1. If you write js as an extension for specific component you will get a reusable, decomposed and maintainable js modules, that can be easily covered by unit tests/refactored in future.
2. Percentage of unused, but loaded in browser js content will be small and more  efficient. End-users should not receive bunches of js for "just in case". Sadly but blazor by itself does not use such frontend optimization and make loads a lot of "just in case" code.
   [coverage for several js modules in comparison to blazor.server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTvCn.png)
3. No need to place a javascript link in render. It brings some benefits:

- prerendered html is not polluted by critical render path blockers ( https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript )
- no need to wait it loaded to invoke some methods after you mark it async to fix render blocking :)
- smaller network overhead for end-users
- out-of-the-box integration to the PWA service-worker.js generated by blazor ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio )